# TinyMCE - Paste on Chrome loses focus

Tags: google-chrome, focus, tinymce, paste

I ran into this problem with the current latest stable of Google chrome browser on Ubuntu 10.04. If I try to paste something using ctrl + v or paste from menu, the content would be pasted but the focus would be lost and go down of page.

May you suggest me solution?

I try everything from here- but nothings work: [What's the best way to set cursor/caret position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253303/whats-the-best-way-to-set-cursor-caret-position)

When I remove plugins : "paste" then it's Ok, so the problem it's come from this plugin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well take a look at the following link

[Focus is lost & \uFEFF inserted when pasting test](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=4391)

Its a bug of TinyMCE and the status ia yet open.Which was submitted at :
2011-05-16 15:15:50 . So hope to be solved by them

Comment: \uFEFF gets inserted when nothing is in the clipboard. The reason is that some browsers can crash whren performing the insertContent-action

Comment: Thanks for answering :) I hope TinyMCE team to fix soon.
For now I'll use indirectly way to resolve problem - maybe scrollIntoView(true) or something like that.