# TinyMCE - Insert Content at the bottom

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I know we can insert the code to the top this way.

ed.selection.setCursorLocation(ed.getBody().firstChild, 0);

But, I am not sure how to implement this for content at the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach:

```
function getTextNodes(node, nodeType, result){

    var children = node.childNodes;
    var nodeType = nodeType ? nodeType : 3;

    var result = !result ? [] : result;
    if (node.nodeType == nodeType) {
        result.push(node);
    }

    for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
        result = this.getTextNodes(children[i], nodeType, result)
    }

    return result;
};

// get all Textnodes from lastchild, calc length
var textnodes = getTextNodes(ed.getBody().lastChild);

// set Cursor to last position
ed.selection.setCursorLocation(textnodes[textnodes.length-1], textnodes[textnodes.length-1].textContent.length );
```

Comment: I'll say: a better approach

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following to [DOMUtils.add()](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.dom.DOMUtils.add) method to add a new HTML element to the document body.

For example, the following adds an empty paragraph with a CSS Class of "text_it"

```
ed.dom.add(ed.getBody(), 'p', {'class' : 'text_it'});
```

Comment: (fourth arg is the content, works with Tiny MCE 6)