# TinyMce ed.selection.select Throws error in Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce

I want to add content to the TinyMce editor automatically at a specific place.
For this i use the following example:

First what you should do is add a span at the end of the content you want to create.

Then once inserted, do this...

ed.selection.select(ed.dom.select('span#caret_pos_holder')[0]); //select the span
ed.dom.remove(ed.dom.select('span#caret_pos_holder')[0]); //remove the span

Found here:
[What's the best way to set cursor/caret position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253303/whats-the-best-way-to-set-cursor-caret-position)

This works fine in de Chrome but throws an error in IE

"DOM Exception: INDEX_SIZE_ERR (1)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function (located in one of my own custom plugins) i use

```
    // sets the caret position
    // ed is the editor instance
    // element is the html element located in the editor
    // start defines if the caret should get set to the start of the element (otherwise the end)
    setCursor: function (ed, element, start) {

        var doc = ed.getDoc();
        var edwin = ed.getWin();
        if (typeof doc.createRange != "undefined") {
            var range = ed.selection.dom.createRng();
            range.selectNodeContents(element);
            range.collapse(start);
            var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
            var sel = tinymce.isIE ? doc.selection : edwin.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (typeof doc.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
            var textRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
            textRange.moveToElementText(element);
            textRange.collapse(start);
            textRange.select();
        }
    },
```

Example call:

```
setCursor(ed, $(ed.getBody()).find('span#caret_pos_holder').get(0), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works in chrome but in ie i get an error that the attribute or method removeAllRanges is not supported by this object.

Comment: you may try to comment "removeAllRanges" out and check again in IE9

Comment: same problem with sel.addRange

Comment: hmm, what about this tinymce core function. does this work: ed.selection.setCursorLocation(node, offset);

Comment: That seems to work, thanks! 

var element = $(ed.getBody()).find('span#'+type).get(0)     ed.selection.setCursorLocation(element, 0);

Comment: glad to have been able to help